# What is the geometry of points inside a square, that are equally distant from the square

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

Image: 
[A visual of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0bA9.png)

For the square ABCD, what would be the geometry of points that are equally distant (distance r) from all points of the square?

How would the shape written out by r look like, and is it possible to define it with a function?

EDIT: "equidistant from all points of the square" means that any point on the vertices of the square ABCD is equally distant to the shape drawn by r on the inside. A more real-life example of the problem could be seen on [this image](https://i.redd.it/m3jstei850h31.jpg), where the square represents the seats and the problem would be "what shape should the table be, so that all people sitting on the seats (all points on the ABCD square) are equally distant to the table?". If it's a square table, it's obviously not ideal, because the person at any of the edges of the square is much further away from the table than the person in the middle of the distance AB for example.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. I don't understand what :equidistant from all points of the square" means. Please [edit] the picture to show all the points you mean, not just one along with a single line segment. Nor is it clear what kind of function you mean. In what context do you need this information?

Comment: Thank you, I have added the explanation that I hopefully addresses all of your comments.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I think this is a better modification of your question: for the square $ABCD$, what is the geometry of the set of the points in the square such that each point on the square is at distance $r$ from that set.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point equally distant to all points of a square. Indeed, if $P$ were such a point, then the triangle $PAB$ is isoscele, as $PA=PB$. Therefore, the orthogonal projection of $P$ on the line $(A,B)$ (sorry if the notation is unusual) is the middle point of the segment $[A,B]$, call it $I$. Such a point belongs to the square, thus $PI=PA=PB$, however, $PAI$ is a square triangle, thus $PA>PI$, contradiction.

Comment: Maybe I have explained myself badly - I'm not looking for a point P which is equally distant from all points of the square, this is obviously not possible. I'm looking for a shape whose outline is, at all points, equally distant to the square. Here's a visualization of one proposal: https://imgur.com/a/rWRkxSI

As we "slide" the r from A to to A', then to B' and B, it draws a shape that it equally distant from all points of the square (just not minimally distant, because the y value of the r for the point B' is < r). However, all points can reach the shape with the distance r.

Comment: @praznin Oh I see. So it has to do with parametrized curves. Though your question is not precise enough as not only you didn't mention that, but looking at your picture you seem to have some requirements concerning the parametrization. Please re-write your question in a clear manner.

Comment: Sorry, I lack the mathematical foundation to rewrite it in such a way. In fact, this is the first time that I'm hearing about parametrized curves. Thanks anyway @Scientifica

Comment: @praznin No problem. I lack knowledge to give a very detailed or general answer, so I can't help you much about it. Your picture is definitly one example, and you can modify it making the shape less symmetric,

Answer (score 0):

If the square $ABCD$ has dimension $s,$ then the locus you want is a smaller square contained in the finite region defined by the first, and concentric with it, so that it has dimension $s-2r.$

Comment: I don't think any square can be a solution to this because https://imgur.com/a/YNTOw0Q r' > r, and all points of the outer square need to be r distant from the inner shape

Comment: @praznin I answered based only on your verbal explanation above. I'll see the picture now, though.

Comment: @praznin I didn't see any image at the linked site. I suggest you enter the image directly into the body of OP. I also suggest editing the verbal parts to more correct mirror the problem.